# FaceBook GraphAPI Retrieves only id,Fname,Lname,photo,id & link

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Am using graph api(v1.0) along with an old appid which was been created before the v2.0 was been released in MVC4 application and trying to get self work history using the code 
FacebookAPI api = new FacebookAPI(Session["access_token"].ToString());
Jsonobject people = api.Get("/me", args); // where args are the FBgeneral fields(id,first_name,last_name,work,education,location,picture,link) here it works fine BUT
when i try to get the same using the same api(v1.0) and newer appid which was been created recently before two months the self users work details not getting retrieved. It only retrieves(id,first_name,last_name,picture,link)

Comment: Could you please format your question properly to make it easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify explicitly the API version to use, the newer Facebook App will use the API v2.0.

> For apps created on or after April 30th 2014, making an API call without a specifing a version number is equivalent to making a call to v2.0 of the API.

src: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

You can check the used Facebook API version by the following HTTP-Header: facebook-api-version

src: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1

Comment: i tried all possibilities but still am not getting the work details i used "/v2.1/me/" it returns 11 objects but not work & education details and when i use it like"/v2.1/me/?fields=work" or "/v2.1/me?fields=work" or "/v2.1/me/?fields=user_work_history" it throws error even i tried changing the url from all.js to sdk.js in fb.init() function but its not working can anyone pls help me out of this,i got strucked for past two days

Comment: user_work_history is not a field, but a permission. You need that permission to retrieve the work field. I tested that and it worked for me. (My test-application was the Graph API Explorer-application.)

Comment: Btw to retrieve the fields education and location you need the permissions "user_education_history" and "user_location".

Comment: Hi  LivingSoftware thanks for your continuous responses can u please post me a sample code which worked for you where work details are getting retrieved please

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/54qrv70n/2/ . You need to specify your own Facebook App ID. Furthermore your app must have "fiddle.jshell.net" as "App Domain" or "http:// fiddle.jshell.net" as "Valid OAuth redirect URI".

Comment: Thanks LivingSoftware i tried with my appid in your jsfiddle and included the app domain and too implemented your code but still i cant able to get the work details

Comment: If i Login using my personal fb credentials the work details gets retrieved but when i try with some others mail-id its not getting retrived.

Then i gave Admin rights to other person for the app which am testing and then checked the work details gets retrieved for him.

From this i found that the work details gets retrieved only for the peoples who have admin rights with the app which is being used in the application.

Comment: I think your app must be reviewed by Facebook before any non-admin users can give you the required permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-user_work_history